# JavaFX Resizing TextField with Window

Tags: javafx, resize, textfield

In JavaFX, how do I create a textfield inside an hbox (BorderPane layout) resize in width/length as the user resizes the window?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set the `HGROW` for the textfield as `Priority.ALWAYS`.

This will enable the `TextField` to shrink/grow whenever the `HBox` changes its width.

**MCVE :**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        TextField textField = new TextField();

        HBox container  = new HBox(textField);
        container.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        container.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        // Set Hgrow for TextField
        HBox.setHgrow(textField, Priority.ALWAYS);

        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        pane.setCenter(container);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 150, 150);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Output :**

[image]

Comment: That worked for me. How do I do the same for a textarea inside a scrollpane?